# Return column unique values of json array, if matches to another column value

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am working on NuxtJs and i have to return a list array from a column of json data when and if matches to a value of another columns

The below code returns all unique value names from the column. But i want to get unique value names when the album name matches to "BAD" / "Thriller" alone

```
getNameList(){
            var lookup = {};
            var items = this.testdata.songs;
            var result_name = [];
            for (var item, i = 0; item = items[i++];) {
                    var unique_name = item.name;
                    if (!(unique_name in lookup)) {
                        lookup[unique_name] = 1;
                        result_name.push(unique_name);
                    }
            }
            return result_name
}
```

Please help me with some codes

json data file name "testdata.json"

```
{
    "songs": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Thriller",
        "album": "Thriller"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Smooth Criminal",
        "album": "BAD"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Thriller",
        "album": "Thriller"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Smooth Criminal",
        "album": "BAD"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "BAD",
        "album": "BAD"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Billy Jean",
        "album": "Thriller"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "BAD",
        "album": "BAD"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Smooth Criminal",
        "album": "BAD"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "BAD",
        "album": "BAD"
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Billy Jean",
        "album": "Thriller"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Smooth Criminal",
        "album": "BAD"
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "Beat It",
        "album": "Thriller"
    },

    {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "Billy Jean",
        "album": "Thriller"
    },
  ]
}
```

I am new to Javascript & nuxtjs. I tried with several if statements between the above script code, but nothing works to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the array by album name and use `Set` to get unique array value.

```js
function getNameList(testdata){
  const filteredArray = testdata.songs
    .filter(item => item.album === 'BAD' || item.album === 'Thriller');
  return [...new Set(filteredArray.map(item => item.name))];
}

const a = {"songs":[{"id":"1","name":"Thriller","album":"Thriller"},{"id":"2","name":"Smooth Criminal","album":"BAD"},{"id":"3","name":"Thriller","album":"Thriller"},{"id":"4","name":"Smooth Criminal","album":"BAD"},{"id":"5","name":"BAD","album":"BAD"},{"id":"6","name":"Billy Jean","album":"Thriller"},{"id":"7","name":"BAD","album":"BAD"},{"id":"8","name":"Smooth Criminal","album":"BAD"},{"id":"9","name":"BAD","album":"BAD"},{"id":"10","name":"Billy Jean","album":"Thriller"},{"id":"11","name":"Smooth Criminal","album":"BAD"},{"id":"12","name":"Beat It","album":"Thriller"},{"id":"13","name":"Billy Jean","album":"Thriller"}]};

console.log(getNameList(a));
```

Comment: Can you suggest me some website or web article, where I can learn these codes?

Comment: You can read this MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array and also some tricks from here
https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore